# Getting only those Facebook events which haven't expired graph api

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to get only those facebook events that haven't expired yet(Upcoming events).

When i use the following query i get all the events including those that have expired long ago.

```
FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/events"
                                     parameters:nil
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make use of the `since` parameter as described in

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/events/#read
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

if you set the timestamp to the current time, you should only see future events:

```
/me/events?since=1417508443
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `time_filter=enum{upcoming,past}`. e.g. if you want upcoming events that have not expired yet, send a request like this

> /page_name_or_id/events?time_filter=upcoming

In this way you don't have to handle timezone issues as with `since=timestamp` query.

Comment: This applies only for page events, not user events it seems.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The fields time_filter and the key upcoming don't exist anymore. I filled a bug report that the endpoint does not work and they told me it never existed.

Comment: @Darkwonder look at the answer date, it is obviously outdated, it was correct answer that's why there are more upvotes

Comment: It still works in v13.
.../events?time_filter=upcoming&include_canceled=true&limit=25&fields=id,name,end_time,start_time

Comment: This also works in v13: 
`...?fields=events.time_filter(upcoming){cover{source},category,description,id,is_canceled,end_time,picture,is_draft,is_online,name,place,start_time,updated_time,event_times}`